# PHP MySQL query WHERE equals AND row does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have been looking and cant find an answer to what im trying to do.
I dont know if a query can be created in the following way.

```
$sql_call = "SELECT table.item,table.item,table.item FROM cust 
        LEFT JOIN contact ON cust.id = contact.client_id 
        LEFT JOIN survey_audit ON cust.id = survey_audit.cust_id 
        WHERE cust.clinic='$clinic_id' AND contact.participate='1' AND survey_audit.survey_id != '$post_survey_id'";
```

The query above, does not do what Im trying to do, and that is:

Get data from tables WHERE cust.clinic=something AND contact.participate=something AND (this is the part im not sure about) inside Survey_audit table, there is no row with this id.

Is it possible to ask sql to find a result where something=something AND is no row in specific table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sort of on the right track.  You simply need to look for cases where `survey_audit.survey_id` is NULL.

```
SELECT table.item,table.item,table.item
FROM cust 
LEFT JOIN contact
  ON cust.id = contact.client_id 
LEFT JOIN survey_audit
  ON cust.id = survey_audit.cust_id 
WHERE cust.clinic='$clinic_id'
AND contact.participate='1'
AND survey_audit.survey_id IS NULL
```

Here is a very useful resource for helping you determine how to form more complex join scenarios.  Your case is the 4th example on this page.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: This answer 100% works. Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude all the elements of the table using a subquery:

```
$sql_call = "SELECT table.item,table.item,table.item FROM cust 
        LEFT JOIN contact ON cust.id = contact.client_id 
        LEFT JOIN survey_audit ON cust.id = survey_audit.cust_id 
        WHERE cust.clinic='$clinic_id' AND contact.participate='1' AND survey_audit.survey_id NOT IN (SELECT survey_id FROM Survey_audit);
```

Comment: Make sure you explain what the error was. Else it's not much of an answer.

Comment: Wow, I never knew you could sub-query.. This is very valuable to me!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you should read more about other types of joins in mysql there are 4 types of joins

1. `INNER JOIN` (JOIN) - matching id's in both tables
2. `LEFT JOIN` - matching id in table A and can be null in Table B
3. `RIGHT JOIN` - matching id in table B and can be null Table A
4. `OUTER JOIN` - can be null in both tables

Recommend you to read the following article
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

So for your question **I guess** you should use `RIGHT JOIN survey_audit` instead of `LEFT JOIN survey_audit`